# How to get authData info from ParseUser object?

Tags: android, parse-platform

If I log in using ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(), I get a ParseUser instance. Debugging, I can inspect an authData JSON field, that holds some keys: id, access_token, expiration_date...
However, how can I get that authData JSON info from code? I've tried parseUser.getJSONObject("facebook"), parseUser.getJSONObject("authData"), etc. but nothing works.

Documentation says nothing: https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseUser.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are able to see required JSON fields i believe ParseFacebookUtils is making successful login. Once login() callback returns user is not null, do this inside Callback.

```
Request.executeMeRequestAsync(Session.getActiveSession(), new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
// callback after Graph API response with user object
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {            
    String fullName = user.getName();
    String email = user.getProperty("email").toString();
    String facebookId = user.getId();

    //Do whatever you want

    }
});
```

Make sure to add right imports. And for email you need to ask permission while logging in.

Comment: Thank you! That seems to be a way to get it. It's a pity that I must make another async request for a data Parse has already downloaded (but stored in a private field). I will get by with this solution for now, but I am concerned because  executeMeRequestAsync() is a deprecated method:-(

Comment: I don't know if we can avoid the another request but try using Request.newMeRequest instead of executeMeRequestAsync. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the parse facebook login:
after login with facebook for the first time

logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground...bla bla bla

then:

```
ParseUser parseUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
 Map<String,Map> authObject = parseUser.getMap("authData");
 Map<String,String> fbParseLoginData =  (Map<String,String>)    authObject.get("facebook");

String parseFacebookId = (String)fbParseLoginData.get("id");

String parseFacebookAuthData = (String)fbParseLoginData.get("access_token");
```

sorry for the bad variable naming ;)

Answer (score -1):

The response to logon is in Rest docs section on user logon and looks as follows:

```
"username": "cooldude6",
  "phone": "415-392-0202",
  "createdAt": "2011-11-07T20:58:34.448Z",
  "updatedAt": "2011-11-07T20:58:34.448Z",
  "objectId": "g7y9tkhB7O",
  "sessionToken": "pnktnjyb996sj4p156gjtp4im"
```

In Rest api it can be consumed as follow:

```
mBmpNode= new ObjectMapper().readValue(new ByteArrayInputStream(response), 
JsonNode.class);
str_id = mBmpNode.path("objectId").getTextValue();   // or 'sessionToken', 'username'
```

look at those JSON element names and just use them instead of what you used and you should be good. Not 'facebook' but a name in the http response like 'objectId'.

You must know the actual , JSON element name...

get that by reading the docs more closely or by using WIRE debugging of the http traffic.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer looks like it has nothing to do with ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(). There are no 'response' parameter, just a ParseUser and a ParseException instances. I know how to get a JSON field from a JSON object, my problem is how to get the JSON object I need in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

```
HashMap hash1 = (HashMap) parseUser.get("authData");

HashMap hash2 = (HashMap) hash1.get("facebook");

String id = hash2.get("id");
```